# java how to call superclass method of T (generics)

Tags: java

I have the following method. I would like to find if T has superclass, if so then call the cloneEntity method of the superclass

```
public Clone(Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
    this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
}

public T cloneEntity(){
  T clonedEntity = typeParameterClass.newInstance();

  Class superClass = typeParameterClass.getSuperclass();
    if(superClass != null){
        //call clone method of the superclass to copy superclass properties
        ?????????
    }
}
```

More explanation

I am not trying to instantiate superclass. I am trying to create an instance of say Address. Address extends BaseEntity and has a deepCopy() method. BaseEntity itself has a deepCopy() method. After creating an instance of Address i want to call the deepCopy() method on Address and then on the superclass BaseEntity

More explanation

I want to get rid of the deepCopy() method in each object like Address, User etc and create a generic one. Hence T could be Address or User, But I would like to call the superclass of T in the generic implementation

Comment: Not that there aren't legitimate reasons to do this, because I'm sure there are, but... Have you considered the notion that if you need to get the superclass and instantiate it, perhaps your design isn't quite generic?

Comment: I am not trying to instantiate superclass. I am trying to create an instance of say Address. Address extends BaseEntity and has a deepCopy() method. BaseEntity itself has a deepCopy() method. After creating an instance of Address i want to call the deepCopy() method on Address and then on the superclass BaseEntity

Comment: Why doesn't the deepCopy() method of Address call BaseEntity's deepCopy() (i.e. super.deepCopy())?

Comment: Yes.  Address.deepCopy() should know that it needs to call super.deepCopy() - you shouldn't have to do it yourself.

Comment: Fellows, my whole point is to eliminate the deepCopy in Address and create a generic one, so that all object can implement it. Hence in the generic implementation of an object, how to call the superclass method

Answer (score 2):

Every class which doesn't explicitly `extends` anything has `java.lang.Object` as a superclass (interfaces and primitives aren't classes), so that check isn't doing what you think it is.

If you want to check if a class implements cloneable, you can do:

```
Cloneable.class.isAssignableFrom( YourType.class );
```

Comment: I am not trying to call any method on Object or Cloneable. I have added more info to my question

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've created an instance of the class, a bad old `instanceof` and a cast should do the trick. However, reflection is almost never the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, calling `clone()` on the superclass would require some reflection hacks, as `clone()` is protected in Object.

But what's wrong with the old-style clone() as defined in Object (and documented in Cloneable) ? That involves always calling super.clone(), so that should be OK for your case.

You'll just need an interface that declares `clone()` as public and then your T should look like `<T extends ThatInterface>`. You can also have an abstract class that implements `ThatInterface` and provides a default implementation for `clone()` -- like the one you're trying to implement in the posted code.